# Converting String to Double is removing trailing zero for a double zero entry in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift, I'm trying to convert the following:

```
String d = "60.00"
Double dd = Double(d)
print(dd) // => 60.0 - removes the last decimal
```

But the following works as expected:

```
String d = "60.01"
Double dd = Double(d)
print(dd) // => 60.01 - last decimal remains
```

Am I converting incorrectly?

Comment: The value is being converted correctly; `60.0` and `60.00` are equivalent. The problem is you’re not formatting your output.

Comment: Your fighting with the internal formatting workflows used to represent the value through the `print` command.  If it's really important to you, you could just use a `NumberFormatter` and will give you control over how you want it displayed

Comment: trailing zeros in decimal places have no meaning for a "number", they are just a kind of visualization for human to read, only exists in string. You can freely choose how to visualize a value as you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output a Double using 2 decimal places you can use a NumberFormatter, or you can use the String initializer `init(format:_:)` (defined as `init(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...)`)

```
let decimal = 60.0
// The format string "%.2f" says "Take the Double value in the next parameter and display it using exactly 2 decimal places."
let string = String(format: "%.2f", decimal)
print(string)
```

That outputs "60.00" as you desire.

Or, using a NumberFormatter:

```
let decimal = 60.0
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
// By setting formatter.minimumFractionDigits & maximumFractionDigits both to 2, 
// you will always get 2 decimal places
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

// NSNumberFormatter's `string(for:)` can fail to convert a value to a String. 

// It returns an Optional, so we need to use `if let` "optional binding" 
// to try to unwrap the Optional.
if let formatterString = formatter.string(for: decimal) {
    print(formatterString)
} else {
    print("Can't convert value using NumberFormatter")
}
```

That also outputs "60.00", but it's more complex to set up.

Comment: Oh thank you! (Edited my answer.) Where is `string(for:)` documented? I don't see it in the docs in Xcode.

Comment: It is declared on Formatter.

Comment: Ah. Silly me. I still manage to forget to check the methods defined in parent classes sometimes. Interesting that the `Formatter` class reference says the base method raises an exception. You'd think Apple would document the version in `NumberFormatter` then, since it **is** a custom implementation.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like for DateFormatters the only real difference is that `string(for:)` returns an `Optional<String>` rather than a `String` like `DateFormatter.string(from:)` does.

Comment: Yes but the main point is that it works with `Any` so you don’t need to instantiate a `NSNumber` object